# Different size for markers (L.icon) on zoom level

Tags: leaflet, size, zooming, marker

I am working on a map in leaflet, and I was wondering how to make two different sizes for icons, where the larger size would activate on the largest zoom level? Currently the icons look far too small on the max zoom level.

This is how the icons' sizes are determined:

```
var playerIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/players.png',  // Location of file to be used as icon.
    iconSize: [38, 38],             // Size of icon on map.
});
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to have something like "iconSize1" and "iconSize2" for each icon, and have the iconSize 2 activate on zoom level 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you zoom the map, the markers are already added on the map? And then you want to change the icon based on zooming level. Is that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You could define 2 icons and swap icons on the marker depending on the zoom....

```
var playerIcon1 = L.icon(....);
var playerIcon2 = L.icon(....);

map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    if (map.getZoom() < 6) {
        marker.setIcon(playerIcon1);
        } else {
        marker.setIcon(playerIcon2);
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but now it only shows the larger icon at all times, not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: I got it working like this:

var playerIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/player.png',  // Location of file to be used as icon.
    iconSize: [20, 20],             // Size of icon on map.
});

var playerIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/player.png',  // Location of file to be used as icon.
    iconSize: [40, 40],             // Size of icon on map.
});


map.on('zoomend', function(ev){
  if (map.getZoom() > 5) {
    player.setIcon(playerIcon2);
  } else {
    player.setIcon(playerIcon1);

  }
})